# Get the content HTML of an API

Tags: python, scrapy, urllib

I'm tring to get the content of an API result in python.
This is an HTML template with an image inside.

I tried lot of method to get the content but it don't work everytime.

**The fuction** :

```
def screenshotlayer(self, access_key, secret_keyword, domain, args):
    domain = "http://" + domain
    url = "http://api.screenshotlayer.com/api/capture?access_key=API_KEY&url=http://google.com&viewport=1440x900&width=250"
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup.findAll('img')[0]['src']
```

When I `print html`, there is lot of incomprehensible characters.
Can someone help me to resove this problem ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: The api does not returns html, but a raw image file (default to png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api does not returns html, but a raw image file (default to png).

You need to see if the `status_code` was 200, and if so, simply save the result into a file.

```
import requests

res = requests.get(
    'http://api.screenshotlayer.com/api/capture',
    params={
        'access_key': 'API_KEY',
        'url': 'http://google.com&viewport=1440x900&width=250'
    }
)
if(res.status_code == 200)
    with open('output.png', 'w+b') as f:
        f.write(res.content.encode('utf8'))
else:
    print('Api returns error: %s' % res.content)
```

Comment: Thanks this exaxmple was something I was looking for :)